# Is there a way to re-order how layers render in Mapnik?

Tags: layers, mapnik, xml

I'm creating Mapnik stylesheets and I am trying to edit the order layers are rendered. I tried just moving the XML code, but that didn't seem to work. Are there specific steps to make some features render above others?